# What does this line of JQUERY mean?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-detail

I would like to add the [jQuery OpenID Plug-in](http://jvance.com/pages/JQueryOpenIDPlugin.xhtml) in my webpage.

Actually i would like to add it into a content page of a MasterPage

```
$(function () { $("form.openid:eq(0)").openid(); });
```

But something goes terribly wrong, and the Javascript code is never executed.

I guess this has to do with the fact that my page renders as follows

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
...
</form>
```

and here comes a part of Javascript called

```
//jQuery OpenID Plugin 1.1
//Copyright 2009 Jarrett Vance http://jvance.com/pages/jQueryOpenIdPlugin.xhtml
$.fn.openid = function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $usr = $this.find('input[name=openid_username]');
```

and the Jquery as follows

```
 $(function () { $("form.openid:eq(0)").openid(); });
```

So what does the line above mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(function () { 
   $("form.openid:eq(0)").openid();  
});
```

Can be broken down to this...

```
   $(function () { 

    });
```

Simply means call the inner function once the page is loaded.

```
$("form.openid:eq(0)").openid();
```

Means call the method `openid()` on the first instance of a form with the cssclass openid.

Answer (score 2):

It means get the first form element has class "openid" then run openid() function

Answer (score 0):

It invokes the method openid() on the first (eq(0)) form-tag with a css class named "openid"
It doesn't get executed since you miss class="openid" on your form-tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$(function () { $("form:eq(0)").openid(); });
```

Your code will look for the first `form` element whose `class` attribute is set to "openid".

Comment: I think your selector get's the first form regardless of it's css class. You probably ment `"form.openid:eq(0)"`